# Programming for Windows with no redistributable

Tags: windows, programming-languages, redistributable

It might be a stupid question, but all of my tries to google this failed. The question is: How can you develop windows applications that don't need a redistributable pre-installed? I want to create applications that run also under older versions of Windows which don't have the .NET Framework or something similar included.

Thank you, eWolf

Comment: @Lasse: No, because it needs a redistributable.
@All: Thanks for the answers! I will start learning C++ now.. I've got a big fat book in front of me which is also supposed to be for complete beginners, but in the first chapter, it already uses tons of expresions I only understand because I already can develop with C# and PHP.. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, program in a native language, such as C++, no CLR.

Second, disable manifest and avoid linking external DLLs (such as STDC or MFC).

Comment: So C++ doesn't need a redistributable? Recently, some software installed "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable" on my computer. When do you need that component?

Comment: You need it when programming in C++ CLI, AKA "managed C++", which is a microsoft's C++-like language that is actually a hybrid between C++ and C#.

Comment: It's needed with versions of Visual C++ more recent than 6 if the application is compiled specifying to the linker to use the dll version of the CRT; the other option is to link the CRT statically in the application, but the final exe size will grow.

Comment: I just want to point out that Matteo Italia provides the correct answer to your question in the comments. If you are developing your application using Visual C++ and don't want to install an extra DLL (the Visual C++ runtime aka CRT) you should configure your project to link to the CRT statically.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by older versions of Windows?
The .net Framework is part of Windows since Windows 2003 and .net 1.1.
So if you are targeting Windows Versions newer than Windows 2003, you can be sure that .net is available.

There are also solutions, that [automate linking/packaging](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#framework.required) of .net products, so that you don't need to ship any redistributables etc.

**Update:**
I just found out that [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) allows you to link the whole runtime into your executable.
They call that feature *Bundle*.
Read more about that [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime#Bundles).

Comment: Perhaps he means old as in Win9x or Windows 2000 where the presence of .NET isn't guaranteed at all.

Comment: Probably, but he tagged the question with .net and redistributable. So we talk about platforms that have some sort of .net support available.

Comment: If I develop for .NET, then for the newest version. It doesn't help me much if .NET 1.1 is available...

Comment: the "newest version" is 3.5 which only comes with Windows 7.  
So you will have to decide between 
1. no prerequisites && old .net Version
-- or --
2. Redistributable && new framework features

New .net on old Windows without any requirements would be nice. 
But that's squaring the circle.

You could also look at Mono's Bundle mechanism. (see the update in my answer)
The state of the Mono APIs compared to .net is "somewhere in between .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5" according to ther FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

Use Delphi - although the newer versions of the IDE have some odd bugs, it is easy to create native windows applications that don't need a redistributable.  Much easier to use than C++/win32.

Comment: You probably are right, but C++ is a language that generally seems to be worth learning it. For sure it's not easy, but it is pretty fast, I think.

Comment: If it's just a learning exercise, then of course you can do what you like.  I doubt that there's a significant speed difference between a C++ app and a Delphi app though since Delphi allows you to get pretty close to the bare metal, as does C++.  

The difference is in the development time - a GUI is much quicker and easier to develop in Delphi than a C++ one.

Comment: If you're intent on C++, you can use C++Builder, which is part of the same IDE (if you buy the RAD Studio product). It also can produce applications without any redistributable requirements. (I once won a bet with a network administrator about writing a Windows app that would run from a 1.44MB floppy without an installation and retrieve information via the WinAPI from his database server machine; I did it using Delphi 2 and collected on the bet. <g>)

Comment: @ken: Cool ;) What kind of database was it?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** As eWolf pointed out he did not need the .NET, despite the original question tagged as .NET.

<strike>In short, some older machines such as Win95/98/2000 may not have the runtime installed. Since you specified .NET, I'm assuming you want to build an application using .NET, there's a big but, you need to have the .NET runtime installed beforehand you can execute the .NET application. You can easily get around that by two methods:</strike>

- Install the .NET runtime manually OR
- Use a custom installer script which can detect if .NET runtime is installed or not, to install the .NET runtime redistributable.

If you are talking about a native application such as C/C++, the best path to take (to avoid dependences and minimize the number of DLL's required) is, develop it in raw WinAPI32, using only the standard DLL's that a lot of Windows machines will have, COMMCTRL.DLL, USER32.DLL, ADVAPI.DLL to name but a few. The end result will be a smaller executable. Of course you can bundle other DLL's by statically linking the DLL's together to form one big mammoth executable.

Comment: No I don't want to build an application using .NET as this requires a runtime - which I don't want. I'm interested in native applications.

Comment: @eWolf: Ok. Can you edit your tags accordingly as you have this tagged as .NET I will edit my answer accordingly too.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't want to add the .NET tag.. corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the [WTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/), which is a lightweight C++ framework.  It's only one step above the Win32 API really, so you get small EXEs with few dependencies.  WTL requires the ATL framework which you can statically link to, meaning you only need to ship your EXE.

Another framework worth looking at is [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).  However, this does require you ship some DLLs with your application.  Qt is a fantastic framework and I think you'll find it more productive than WTL (depending on your application needs of course.)

Comment: This sounds interesting. Which environment would you recommend for C++? Should I use Visual C++ or gcc? Is there some kind of form designer available?

Comment: I also found interesting the SmartWin++ toolkit, although its development stopped some years ago.

Comment: If you opt for WTL then use Visual Studio.  If you go for Qt then they have a superb C++ IDE (complete with form editor) called Qt Creator.